# Shiny Leaflet R Won't Correctly Change Color of Circle Markers

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to make a leaflet map in shiny so that the user is able to select a variable and the map will color the markers according to the variable that the user has selected. I am able to color the markers but unfortunately the colors aren't corresponding to the selected variable. So, for example, if the user chooses to color by "Year" all points from the same year should be colored the same, but this is not the case. What am I missing?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

SampleData <- data.frame(year = c('2017', '2018', '2017', '2020'),
                         lon = c(38.62893, 38.62681, 38.62797, 38.62972),
                         lat = c(-90.26233, -90.25272, -90.26232, -90.25703),
                         month = c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April'),
                         new_use = c('Industrial', 'Institutional', 'Commercial', 'Residential'))

vars <- c(
  "Color by Year" = "year",
  "Color by Month" = "month",
  "Color by Use" = "new_use"
)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
    absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                  pickerInput(inputId = "month", 
                              label = "Select Month:", 
                              choices = sort(unique(SampleData$month)), 
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              selected = sort(unique(SampleData$month)),
                              options = list(
                                `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$month))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Months")),
                  pickerInput(inputId = "year", 
                              label = "Select Year:", 
                              choices = sort(unique(SampleData$year)), 
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              selected = sort(unique(SampleData$year)),
                              options = list(
                                `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$year))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Years")),
                  pickerInput(inputId = "new_use", 
                              label = "Select Permit Use:", 
                              choices = sort(unique(SampleData$new_use)), 
                              multiple = TRUE,
                              selected = sort(unique(SampleData$new_use)),
                              options = list(
                                `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                                `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$new_use))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Permit Types")),
                  selectInput(inputId = "color",
                              label = "Select a Color Scheme:", 
                              choices = vars)
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% 
            setView(lng = -90.1994, lat = 38.6270, zoom = 10)%>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
    })
    
    # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
    filteredData <- reactive({
        dplyr::filter(SampleData, year %in% input$year & new_use %in% input$new_use & month %in% input$month)
    })
  
observe({
  
  colorBy <- input$color

    if (colorBy == "year") {
      colorData <- sort(unique(SampleData$year))
      pal <- colorFactor("Set1", colorData)
     } 
    if (colorBy == "month") {
      colorData <- sort(unique(SampleData$month))
      pal <- colorFactor("Set1", colorData)
    }
    if (colorBy == "dayNight") {
      colorData <- sort(unique(tot$dayNight))
      pal <- colorFactor("Set1", colorData)
    }
  
        leafletProxy("map") %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addCircleMarkers(data = filteredData(), 
             ~lat, ~lon, color = pal(colorData), popup = paste("<b>Year:</b> ", filteredData()$year, "<br>",
                  "<b>Permit Type:</b> ", filteredData()$new_use, "<br>")) %>%
       addLegend("bottomright", pal=pal, values=colorData, title=colorBy,
         layerId="colorLegend")
    })
}    
    


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colorFactor needs categorical data

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)

SampleData <- data.frame(year = c('2017', '2018', '2017', '2020', '2018', '2018', '2017'),
                         lon = c(38.62893, 38.62681, 38.62797, 38.62972, 38.624, 38.6245, 38.6252),
                         lat = c(-90.26233, -90.25272, -90.26232, -90.25703, -90.264, -90.265, -90.266),
                         month = c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'February', 'March', 'April'),
                         new_use = c('Industrial', 'Institutional', 'Commercial', 'Residential',  'Institutional', 'Commercial', 'Residential'))

vars <- c(
  "Color by Year" = "year",
  "Color by Month" = "month",
  "Color by Use" = "new_use"
)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                pickerInput(inputId = "month", 
                            label = "Select Month:", 
                            choices = sort(unique(SampleData$month)), 
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            selected = sort(unique(SampleData$month)),
                            options = list(
                              `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                              `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$month))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Months")),
                pickerInput(inputId = "year", 
                            label = "Select Year:", 
                            choices = sort(unique(SampleData$year)), 
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            selected = sort(unique(SampleData$year)),
                            options = list(
                              `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                              `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$year))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Years")),
                pickerInput(inputId = "new_use", 
                            label = "Select Permit Use:", 
                            choices = sort(unique(SampleData$new_use)), 
                            multiple = TRUE,
                            selected = sort(unique(SampleData$new_use)),
                            options = list(
                              `actions-box` = TRUE, 
                              `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(sort(unique(SampleData$new_use))) -1), `count-selected-text` = "All Permit Types")),
                selectInput(inputId = "color",
                            label = "Select a Color Scheme:", 
                            choices = vars)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      setView(lng = -90.1994, lat = 38.6270, zoom = 10)%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
  })
  
  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    dplyr::filter(SampleData, year %in% input$year & new_use %in% input$new_use & month %in% input$month)
  })
  
  observe({
    
    colorBy <- input$color
    
    if (colorBy == "year") {
      colorData <- factor(SampleData$year)
      pal <- colorFactor(palette = "Set1", levels = levels(colorData))
    } 
    if (colorBy == "month") {
      colorData <- factor(SampleData$month)
      pal <- colorFactor(palette = "Set1", levels = levels(colorData))
    }
    if (colorBy == "dayNight") {
      colorData <- factor(tot$dayNight)
      pal <- colorFactor(palette = "Set1", levels = levels(colorData))
    }
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = filteredData(), 
                       ~lat, ~lon, color = ~pal(colorData), popup = paste("<b>Year:</b> ", filteredData()$year, "<br>",
                                                                         "<b>Permit Type:</b> ", filteredData()$new_use, "<br>")) %>%
      addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = levels(colorData), title = colorBy,
                layerId = "colorLegend")
  })
}    



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. The values in my legend aren't matching the values displayed on the map. This also make my map run much slower for some reason. It takes almost a minute to render the circle markers. Any ideas?

Comment: In the example, it seems to work well. There may be some deviation from the example to your actual data.

Comment: Try these adjustments.

Comment: Thank you! I also figured out why it was running so slowly. I should have been calling on `filteredData()` in my `if` statement as opposed to `sampleData`